# Mass assign roles to the list of users discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This code assigned specified role to a list of members.
The problem when I try to get the member with userID from message.guild.members.

Code

```
// !roleAssign @role 
const roleAssign = async function(message){
  const Role = message.mentions.roles.first();
  // split by new line
  const users = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\r?\n/).slice(1);

  let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();

  users.forEach(user => {
    const u = client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag === user);
    if(u){
      const userId = u.id;
  
      // member with the userID
      let member = members.cache.get(userId);

      // give role to the member
      try{
        member.roles.add(Role)
      }
      catch(e){console.error(e)};
  });

}
```

I get this error.
How do I use get function with fetched members?

```
let member = members.cache.get(userId);
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [`guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a collection, not a `GuildMemberManager` that has a `cache` property. It means, you can use `Collection#get()` like this, without the `cache`:

```js
let member = members.get(userId);
```